# Select where field in values (if field in value not exist return as null)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select a data in where clause. Say that I have $values: 1,2,3,4

And then I want to select rows from table in that values.

```
  SELECT `date` from another_table where id in (1,2,3,4)
```

If `another_table` only have rows with id 1,2 and 3 only, it mean that the id of 4 is not exist. I want the id of 4 is still selected with return of null or nol or NEVER.

```
      another_table
     -------+-------------+
     |  id  |  date       |
     ----------------------    
         1     Yesterday
         2      Today
         3      Tomorow
         5      Today
```

The expected result would be

```
     -------+-------------+
     |  id  |  date       |
     ----------------------    
         1     Yesterday
         2      Today
         3      Tomorow
         4      Never
```

How to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Understanding your question is probably harder than answering it.  Can you show us by way of example what result you want to get from `another_table`?

Comment: how far do the numbers go? to do this, you need another table with all of the numbers, or a dynamic view

Comment: 1000000 or more numbers

Comment: Typically, issues of data display (as opposed to data storage and retrieval) is best handled in application level code (e.g. a bit of PHP)

Comment: @strawberry, it's not about data display, but its about how to do a tricky ways in geting data from database. it is a long story why I ended up with this method.

Comment: No. It isn't. That data isn't in the database.

Comment: lol, what does it mean?

Comment: '4' is not in the database. So you are not getting that data from the database!

Comment: I told you it's a long story browww.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As one option use an inline view as a rowsource, and perform an outer join operation. We can use an IF expression to check whether a matching row was returned from `another_table`, we know the `id` value will not be NULL if there was a matching row, the join predicate (in the ON clause) guarantees us that.)

As an example:

```
SELECT n.id
     , IF(a.id IS NULL,'Never',a.date) AS `date`
  FROM ( SELECT 1 AS id
         UNION ALL SELECT 2
         UNION ALL SELECT 3
         UNION ALL SELECT 4
       ) n
  LEFT
  JOIN another_table a
    ON a.id = n.id
 ORDER BY n.id
```

The inline view query gets executed, and the results are *materialized* into a temporary table (MySQL calls it a *derived table*).  When the outer query runs, `n` is effectively a table containing 4 rows.

Obviously, if the list of `id` values has to change, you'd need to change the view definition. The SQL text for the inline view can be generated dynamically from an array in a programming language from an array.

For a large number of values, the inline view becomes unwieldy, and you'd get better performance from a table, rather than the view.

Comment: was just about to post the same answer - of course this needs to change depending on the range of possible `ids`

Comment: first of all, thanks for the answer. But should I write `UNION ALL SELECT` million times if I have millions number?

Comment: @iyal: The inline view is just one approach. But the point is, to return those values (1,2,3,4) as values of column in the resultset, you need some sort of rowsource to provide those values. The example inline view pattern I demonstrated is a convenient way for us to (effectively) create a temporary table and populate it within a query. You could also do a separate `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE n (id INT);` and `INSERT INTO n (id) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4);` and then reference `n` as a table in your query.  `... FROM n LEFT JOIN ...`.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try (create temporary table and Left Join from it)

Comment: if i have millions number range and making insert into temporary table millions times, the query will so be so slowwwwwww. ?????

Comment: @iyal: You could use a regular table, and populate it once. If you want to populate all integer values between 1 and some huge number n, you can get that done by doing a cross join of table (e.g. `d`) that contains 10 rows, integer values 0 thru 9. To get values 1 thru 10000 e.g.  `INSERT INTO n (id) SELECT u.i*1000 + h.i*100 + t.i*10 + o.id + 1 AS id FROM d u CROSS JOIN d h CROSS JOIN d t CROSS JOIN d o`

Comment: Upzz I forgot one thing: Thank you very much for the help.